# How to send the escape character on OS X terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

Connecting with telnet looks like this:

```
$ telnet some.host
Trying 10.1.2.3...
Connected to some.host.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I'm running this on the OS X Leopard terminal.  Question is, how do I send this escape character?  On a Linux terminal I'd try <kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd>, but I cannot figure out how to do this on OS X.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The `^]` means <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + right bracket. As strange as that is, it works. You'll be taken to the telnet prompt, where you can type `quit`.

On international keyboards the ] character is often not a single key, and needs to be replaced with some other key. The correct key is typically the key to the right of P or the next key after that.

Here's a list based on comments below:

- Finnish, Swedish, Norwegian, Danish: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>å</kbd>
- French: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>
- German: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ü</kbd>
- Swiss: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>¨</kbd>
- Hungarian: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>
- Portuguese: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd>
- Dutch, Belgian: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>$</kbd>
- Canadian French: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ç</kbd>
- Italian: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

Comment: Ctrl+] is right!

Comment: Ahhh, of course.  Except that with my Finnish keyboard layout, it's control + å.  Naturally.   Thanks :)

Comment: And on the french keyboard it’s `ctrl-6`.

Comment: On German Keyboard on OSX it is CTRL-Ü (Umlaut U)

Comment: On a Swiss Keyboard it is Ctrl-¨. Why o why did the telnet developer need to use the group separator GS. So difficult to type on foreign keyboards.

Comment: on Hungarian (and many more) it is `Ctrl+5`

Comment: Ctrl+å in sweden

Comment: On a belgian keyboard it is ctrl + $

Comment: This doesn't work on newer OSX machines, at least not with iTerm.

Comment: In Spanish/Latin Keyboard it is `Ctrl` + `5`

Comment: Nothing works w/ Japanese keyboard.

Comment: Turkish Ctrl + Shift + Ü

Comment: Another method is to find out which key combination produces the `]` key (on a German keyboard it's option-6) and then press those together with the ctrl key (German: ctrl-option-6). Both methods (incl. ctrl-ü) work on macOS 10.13 in Terminal.app).

Comment: Form me on a German Keyboard Layout its also `ctrl + 5`

Comment: In a Portuguese keyboard it is `CTRL + 5`, not `CTRl + ´`

Comment: This is insane  
On Czech QWERTZ keyboard, it was Ctrl+AltGr+G

Answer (score 2):

Workaround for those who have problems finding the shortcut:

1. Change your systems keyboard language to U.S international - PC (System Settings/keyboard/input sources)
2. Look at an image of a US keyboard layout and ctrl+] the corresponding keys on your keyboard

Comment: The accepted answer gives some international examples, but this (especially part 2) is the more generic explanation.