# How do I exit telnet?

Tags: windows, telnet

I start telnet by `telnet host port`. How do I stop it in Windows? Shockingly, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to the trenches, nothing is "shocking" on Windows.

Comment: @Pacerier `telnet` predates Windows, and Microsoft had excellent UI standards in the 80s and 90s.

Comment: The reason Ctrl+C doesn't interrupt or suspend the connection is that an interrupt signal or a Ctrl+C often needs to be passed through to the remote end (so you can break programs there, if you're working on a remote shell), which wouldn't be possible if the telnet client intercepted it for its own purposes.

Answer (score 701, accepted):

It should have printed something along the lines of:

```
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Since `^X` is  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> for `^]`.

You should then enter the telnet console, where you can enter `quit` to leave telnet.

Comment: on Windows, run telnet with out arguments to see what the escape character is. On some localized Windows versions where ] is only available with `Alt Gr` key, the key combination is `Ctrl`+`+`.

Comment: As far as I remember Ctrl+5 was equivalent with ^] on my (Norwegian) keyboard.

Comment: Ctrl+¨ on Windows 7 and sv/fi layout.

Comment: On `Ubuntu` `Ctrl + ]`, `quit` worked for me

Comment: Doesn't work. It says: `Microsoft Telnet> ^]` and next line shows: `Invalid Command. type ?/help for help`

Comment: @Pacerier Type quit after that to back to the dos. Good Luck.

Comment: From CMD write telnet "hostip/name" "portnumber" then do disconnect.
Press down the CTRL key and another random key on the keyboard until you find the correct one. And then write "quit" press enter.

Comment: I never noticed that before... amazing whats right in front of your face

Comment: It's CTRL+$  (i tested this on windows 10)

This is the output from my console:

 Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client

 Escape Character is 'CTRL+$'


 Microsoft Telnet> quit

 C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Comment: ... and on my German keyboard it was Strg+AltGr+9, then hit return

Comment: On my swedish keyboard it was `Ctrl`+`¨`

Comment: @Krycke The same for Swiss Keyboard, the key `]` must be used with `AltGr` but for that purpose, we just press the `Ctrl`+`¨`

Comment: On German keyboar layout, press `Strg` + `Alt Gr` + `9`

Comment: On Swiss German Keyboard it is CTRL+¨

Comment: On my Mac with Norwegian keyboard, `]` is `Alt` + `9`. Typing `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `9` yields `9` and is not recognised by telnet as escape character. I had to switch to U.S. input source under `Keyboard` --> `Input Sources` to be able to type `Ctrl` + `]`.

Comment: To add to rlovtang's answer: The ] character on US keyboard layout is what is marked as the ^¨ key on the norwegian keyboard.

Comment: actually, I discovered that you don't have to switch keyboard layout. With the norwegian layout it's as easy as typing: `ctrl + å` as you can see in the quoted answer below. Solution in other keyboard language layouts is also listed there.

Comment: In Latinamerican layout is `ctrl + } `

Comment: Ctrl + Ç on PT-BR keyboard

Comment: On danish keyboard for windows: As with @rlovtang suggestion of switching keyboard. Alt + Shift to switch keyboard language or select directly in the buttom right corner of the Task Bar. Then ctrl + ¨ (where ¨ results in ])

Comment: with german keyboard layout on macos `CTRL+OPTION+6` then type close and enter

Comment: In turkish keybord, for Windows,  it's CTRL+ü

Comment: On Croatian keyboard: CTRL + č

Comment: `ctrl+5` worked on my german keyboard

Comment: On a Mac with German layout, type ctrl-option-6 (where option-6 gives `]`) to get into command mode, then type `quit` + return.

Comment: Estonian keyboard: CTRL + Õ, type quit, enter.

Comment: For PT-PT keyboard is ```ctrl+5```

Comment: this does NOT work all the time....the next answer `quit` does work all the time

Comment: `CTRL` + `+` here on Windows 10 with german layout

Comment: @Sebastian Same and I still can't exit

Comment: I always forget about this! why is so different? :(:( thanks!!
it wokrs on ubuntu too.

Comment: Protip: Use On-screen keyboard to figure out where that bloody `]` is located with current keyboard layout :)

Comment: On German keyboard `CTRL`+`5` and then type `quit` to leave.

Answer (score 165):

Type `quit` to exit telnet in windows.

Comment: Worked on MacOS X as well ;)

Comment: Also works in Linux.

Comment: From @Isaac: This also works on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Only this works to me.

Comment: It didn't in linux [Centos 6.6]

Comment: @Alexander you have to press `Ctrl + ]` and only then when `telnet>` prompt appears enter `quit`.

Comment: For some reason I get `Microsoft Telnet> ^]    Invalid Command. type ?/help for help` but `quit` works. Thanks.

Comment: This applies to the telnet interpreter, and not to a running telnet connection, that was asked for

Answer (score 63):

> The `^]` means <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + right bracket. As strange as that is,
> it works. You'll be taken to the telnet prompt, where you can type
> `quit` or simply `q`.
>
> On international keyboards the ] character is often not a single key,
> and needs to be replaced with some other key. The correct key is
> typically the key to the right of P or the next key after that.
>
> Here's a list based on comments below:
>
> - Norwegian: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>å</kbd>
> - Danish, Finnish, and Swedish: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>¨</kbd> [added by Fredrik C]
> - French: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>
> - German, Turkish: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ü</kbd>
> - Swiss: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>¨</kbd>
> - Hungarian: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ú</kbd>
> - Portuguese: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd>
> - Dutch, Belgian: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>$</kbd>
> - Canadian French: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ç</kbd>
> - Italian: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

Quote from @jtbandes answer here: https://superuser.com/a/427/192525
All creds to him.

PS: Answer reproduced here for your convenience, since google took me to this question first, and none of the other answers here was sufficient for my case. The question [How to send the escape character on OS X terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/398/how-to-send-the-escape-character-on-os-x-terminal) could be seen as a duplicate (more generic version) of this question, since the OP's problems are basically the same.

Comment: French keyboard  here on Win7 with a remote session on a Ubuntu 17.10 VM via Putty. 
I got the telnet prompt back with ctrl+5 not ctrl+6

Comment: For my German keyboard it's actually ctr++, not ctr+ü

Comment: If you use Turkish Q on ubuntu CTRL + 5 is the key

Comment: If you use latin american spanish CTRL+5 is the key too

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Portuguese. (Windows 10). Also, telnet says the escape char is ']', not '^]'.

Comment: @D.Pardal The `^` in `^]` just refers to the CTRL button, since it is marked by an `^` on the keyboard. So it just means `CTRL + ]` so telnet is right that the character itself is just `]`

Comment: Thank @GustavoAriasMéndez in Spanish keyboard using SSL terminal conected to unix, control + 5 works!

Comment: On Hungarian layout the key is ctrl+ú

Comment: On Linux (including WSL) you can run `showkey -a` to check the characters which a terminal application receives. You can then try to press various key combinations to find `^]`. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1366082/67132

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Comment: If you use Czech layout, `Ctrl` + `Alt Gr` + `G` is the escape key. Note you can make `telnet` use any escape key you like, with the -e option, e.g. `-e ^F` for Ctrl+F key.

Comment: @dominikandreas Slightly of topic: On Linux (Ubuntu) I have to choose the combination Strg+AltGr+9 (Strg++ is mapped only to "+").

Comment: On Swedish keyboard it was `ctrl` + `¨`

Answer (score 10):

On debian 9, typing :

```
Ctrl + $
```

Allows you to show the prompt from telnet, then only type :

```
q
```

To exit

Comment: It works on Ubuntu as well :)

Comment: The only combinaison OK for me (French keyboard)

Answer (score 2):

all previous answers correct but for this worked:

```
Ctrl + ]
```

then I typed

```
quit
```

Answer (score 1):

"How do I stop it in **Windows**?"

I miss the good old ALT + 29 ¹ on the numeric keypad. And then "quit".
This works since DOS and (should) work across all KB layouts in windows.
Tested 2023 with a  Greek Island layout on windows 11.

¹ With ALT + number on numpad you get all ASCII codes.

^A is 1, ^B is 2 … ^[ is 27 (as ESC) and finally ^] is 29

ALT + 64 -> @

ALT + 64 -> A

Comment: Upvoted: Tested, worked on a Simplified Chinese keyboard in Windows 11.