# access 192.168.0.1 with CMD

Tags: cmd.exe, wifi-configuration

I need some help to create a .bat file which need to:

1) Access 192.168.0.1 or tplinklogin.net (my wi-fi router address)

2) Type/insert user and password

3) Click/run "Disconnect" wait 1-3 sec

4) Click/run "Connect" wait 3-5 sec

5) Click/run "Refresh" - not really necessary

6) Exit

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/puvRZ.png]

Comment: You won't be able to do this with just a batch script, but all the same, we are not a scripting service.  So provide us with what you have attempted so far

Comment: If your router supports telnet, you can google an already written script.

Comment: You are probably after a program like "CURL" which can do web requests).  Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710748/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console

Comment: I have exactly the same requirement, but so far the only way I have found to do it is with a script for the Selenium add-on for Firefox. Unfortunately, the TP-Link router does not use form fields, so I have not found a way to get get `curl` to log in. @Divin3 suggests an approach that I hadn't considered, so I'll investigate and let you know. I have found that my TD-W9980 does support Telnet, and it looks promising.

Comment: I haven't found how to do the disconnect, but I can reboot. I will use this only if desperate, as it interrupts any current intranet activity.

Comment: @AFH telnet uses `quit` to disconnect. [link](https://superuser.com/questions/486496/how-do-i-exit-telnet)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this link](http://forum.tp-link.com/showthread.php?7349-TD-W8970-reboot-script&p=20858&viewfull=1#post20858), which seems more or less to answer the problem, though the Linux script above it worked rather better. I found that the process termination code towards the end didn't work properly, so I took it out and all was well. I also changed the service commands in line with the discussion below and finished up with:-

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd"
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.AppActivate "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "telnet 192.168.0.1~"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "admin~"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "admin~"
WScript.Sleep 2000
WshShell.SendKeys "wan set service pppoa_0_38_0_d --protocol pppoa --conntrigger manual~"
WScript.Sleep 12000
WshShell.SendKeys "~"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "wan set service pppoa_0_38_0_d --protocol pppoa --conntrigger always~"
WScript.Sleep 6000
WshShell.SendKeys "~"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "logout~"
WScript.Sleep 6000
WshShell.SendKeys "~"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "exit~"
```

You simply copy this to a file with a `.vbs` suffix, edit it to update the router's IP address, the log-in user and password, and the service name and protocol. For the latter you will need to log into `telnet` manually and type:

```
wan show service
```

In your `cmd` script, invoke the edited script with:

```
start [/wait] reconnect.vbs
```

Use `/wait` if you want the script to complete before you continue to the next command.

One problem I found is that if called while the router is on-line it leaves it in a disconnected state, but increasing the delay between the two service calls fixed this, and you may need to tweak this or some of the other delays.