# How to send escape character on telnet session while using Powershell 7 with a Portuguese keyboard layout

Tags: windows-10, powershell, telnet, windows-terminal

I've started a telnet session (ex.: `telnet ip port`) and I'm wondering if anyone knows how to send the escape char so that I can get the `telnet>` prompt back.

I've already found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/398/how-to-send-the-escape-character-on-os-x-terminal/427#427), but it seems like it's not working. Btw, I'm using the Portuguese (pt-PT) keyboard layout.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following AutoHotkey script will send <kbd>Esc</kbd> when
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> is pressed (any other character can be used):

```
^y::send, {Esc}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: I'll take a look at it. thanks.